# Need SQL statement to return records that return Null

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here's the three tables I'm working with:

[image]

This is the SQL statement I'm working with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employees.Corps_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name, Employees.Home_Phone, Employees.Mobile_Phone
FROM Shifts INNER JOIN (Employees INNER JOIN Employees_Shifts ON Employees.Employee_ID = Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID) ON Shifts.Shift_ID = Employees_Shifts.Shift_ID
WHERE Shifts.Start_Date_Time Between #11/1/2015# And #12/1/2015# And  Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID = NULL ;
```

What I really need this query to do is examine all the Shifts over the date range indicated and return only those Employee records that **don't** match up.

I've tried changing the INNER operator to LEFT in a couple places but Access just keeps complaining and won't run the query.  I definitely need some help with this one.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Employees.Corps_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name, Employees.Home_Phone, Employees.Mobile_Phone
FROM Employees 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * from Employees_Shifts 
    JOIN Shifts ON Shifts.Shift_ID = Employees_Shifts.Shift_ID
    WHERE Shifts.Start_Date_Time Between #11/1/2015# And #12/1/2015# 
    AND Employees_Shifts.Employee_ID = Employees.Employee_ID
    )
```

Btw DISTINCT often indicate some problem with schema or query, always ask why You need it.